# Check if IP exists in database (sent in via $_SERVER)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending the IP into the database by storing $_SERVER(REMOTE_ADDR) into a global variable, but I am having trouble trying to check if the IP of the host exists or not.

Following is the script I am trying to work with.

```
<?php
    include_once('./db.php');
?>  
<?php
$_SESSION[“sidIP”] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$checkIP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guardiansInfo WHERE sidIP = '".$_SESSION["sidIP"] . "'");

 if(mysql_numrows($checkIP) > 0) {
  echo 'It exists!';
 } else {
  echo 'It does not exist';
 }

 ?>


<html>
    <body>
        nothing


    </body>
</html>
```

This currently gives me this error in apache's log:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ... DIRECTORY

What am I doing wrong?

I am a beginner... Go easy on me. '

EDIT: To those people that are here for answers and don't want to deal with idiotic comments: https://ghostbin.com/paste/kxa4v - I am a beginner, something stackoverflow does not have a concept of.

Comment: it's the funky quotes and is *off-topic*

Comment: Put dots to concatenate the strings: `' . $_SESSION["sidIP"] . '`

Comment: The `"` are wrong. Also, don't use "smart" quotes, `$_SESSION[“sidIP”]`. Currently your assignment says this `SELECT * FROM guardiansInfo WHERE sidIP = '$_SESSION[` is a string because of your quote encapsulation.

Comment: Don't use MS Word for development.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how is this off-topic if my tag specifically says php and mysql, I will try that user4035. And I will attempt to fix this chris85. Thank you for your replies. I will let you guys know what works. I have spent the past 2 days on this. :|

Comment: @chris85 i removed smart quotes. error still exists.

Comment: That was my second comment. The first being `The " are wrong.`. I expanded on that in the latter part of that comment..."Currently your assignment says this `SELECT * FROM guardiansInfo WHERE sidIP = '$_SESSION[` is a string because of your quote encapsulation".

Comment: I actually disagree with the duplicate mark, but there's no point re-opening this question just to close it with a different duplicate. The problem is use of smart quotes; something we have to teach every new developer these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string literal is incorrectly formed.

Arrays will not automatically expand inside double quotes without help.

```
$checkIP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guardiansInfo WHERE sidIP = '{$_SESSION["sidIP"]}'");
```

> Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)